# How to repeat network calls using RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have an API that lets me retrieve an item by an id using something like this:

```
http://myapi.com/api/v1/item/1
```

Where the last value is the id of the item. This is fine and dandy, I can write a Retrofit service interface and call for the item like this:

```
MyService service = MyService.retrofit.create(MyService.class);

service.itemById(1)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Item>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Item item) {
                        adapter.addItem(item);
                    }
                });
```

The problem I run into is that I want to retrieve 5 items at a time, but I don't know how I can do that. If for example I want to get items with id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, how can I do this in one group? I've looked into `Observable.zip()` but I can't quite figure out how to set this up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use zip, you'd want to do something like this (lambda syntax for brevity):

```
Observable.zip(
    service.itemById(1),
    service.itemById(2),
    service.itemById(3),
    service.itemById(4),
    service.itemById(5),
    (i1, i2, i3, i4, i5) -> new Tuple<>(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(
        tuple -> {
            // < use the tuple >
        },
        error -> {
            // ...
        }
    );
```

Note: You'd have to either create a Tuple class, or some other object, or import a Tuple library.

---

Another variation based on your comment:

```
Observable.range(1, 5)
    .flatMap(t -> service.itemById(t), (i, response) -> new Tuple<>(i, response))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe...
```

This will run your requests in parallel and your subscription block will receive each element separately.

---

```
Observable.range(1, 5)
    .flatMap(t -> service.itemById(t), (i, response) -> new Tuple<>(i, response))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe...
```

This will collect the resulting tuples in an array.

Comment: So, how would you do this if I didn't want to hardcode the values? Let's say I wanted to take a starting point, and loop five from that point? (Almost like a pager, if that makes sense)

Comment: Thanks for the edits! I'm gonna go try it right now.

Comment: You're wonderful! I went with the option that received each option separately, but thanks for adding the other one. Will definitely be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Observable<List<YourType>> list = Observable.range(/*...*/).map(/*...*/).toList();